# Grails - Make Embedded Field in Domain Class Nullable

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can you specify an embedded field as nullable?  In the simple example below I want the field price to be nullable, if there is no price associated with the item.  However, if there is a price, both fields in the Currency are required.  The following code doesn't work.  When I try to save the Item, it complains about null values for the currency fields.

```
 class Item {
  static constraints = {
    price(nullable:true)
  }
  static embedded = ['price']
  Currency price
}

class Currency {
  Integer quantity
  String currencyType
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a `static constraints` in your embedded object.

```
class Currency {
...
    static constraints = {
        quantity(nullable:true)
        currencyType(nullable:true,validator:{ String val, Currency obj -> 
            if ((val && !obj.quantity) || (!val && obj.quantity)) {
                return 'Currency.both.fields.required';
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Then, just add `'Currency.both.fields.required'` to your `messages.properties` to display the appropriate error.

Comment: That isn't quite what I am looking for.  This will allow me to have no currency, but it will also allow me to have a currency that has a currencyType and no quantity or a quantity with no currencyType.  So that doesn't fit the business rules I'd like the constraints to impose.

Comment: At that point you can add a custom validator to verify both fields are set.  I've updated my response to show how that can be done.

Comment: Yes, that would work.  Thanks.  I just wish the original code worked.  It seems prettier.